# keeping button states when changing activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to make an application that has 4 states, however, two of the buttons are common to all 4 states, and are meant to do the same thing. I was wondering if there is any code that can change the state of a button from the beginning of the activity, like when starting the intent to check for the current state of the two buttons and start the new intent with the states updated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this with a static boolean variable and a toggle button.

```
static boolean button;
ToggleButton bClock;

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (bClock.isChecked() == true) {
            button = true;
        } else
            button = false;

    }

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onStart();
        if (button == true) {
            bClock.setChecked(true);
        }
```

You could make two of those to share the button states between two buttons. I hope that helps

Comment: From what I understand, the code is for keeping the buttons pressed for when the activity is resumed. I want to set the buttons as checked in all 4 states and to be accessible to uncheck in any of them and saving as well for all 4.

Comment: Okay, but I think you could use a switch and case to toggle the global static boolean and then use if's in each button to check the status of it.